# language.button_continue + LocalizedStrings

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

The metadadata language.button_continue was working properly, the labels of the buttons was respecting the value of metadata, then I started using the localized strings (current, just 1 language) to centralize the language/translations, and now the label of the buttons just respect the value from LocalizedString or the DisplayName from ClaimSchema.

I tried some combinations off Append/prepend/replaceall and "language.PT-BR.button_continue", but none worked. What is the correct usage of language.button metadata + LocalizedStrings ?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-localization) which shows you how to support multiple locales or languages in the policy for user journeys. Localization requires three steps: set-up the explicit list of supported languages, provide language-specific strings and collections, and edit the content definition for the page.

Comment: Yes, I checked, and I made these confs, the LocalizedStrings is working properly, the point is how to make language.button at metadata's TP override the LocalizedStrings when I need just to change the buttons labels.

Comment: Please check the way how you can [customize the strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-language-customization#customize-your-strings)

Comment: did this issue got resolved for you.?